# Insoluble system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

**Determine the coordinates of the polynomial p = $1 + x + x^2 + x^3$ in the base B' doesn't work.**

I am doing a task where I have determined the transition matrices for base switching between the bases where B=${1,x,x^2,x^3}$ and B′ =${1−x,x+x^2,1+2^x+x^3,x−x^2 +x^3}$.

And after that I found the matrix for the linear image $T: P3 → P3, T (p) = p'' + p' + p$ relative to base $B'$. This went well and I got the transition matrices and linear image to (putting this if needed):

$$Transition \ matrice \ B' \ to \ B: \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$Transition \ matrice \ B \ to \ B': \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1  & 1 & 2 \\ -1 & -1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$Linear \ image: \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3  & 3 & 3 \\ -1 & 3 & 8 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 31\end{pmatrix}$$

And for my last part I am going to find the coordinates of the polynomial p = $1 + x + x2 + x3$ in base B' and I have tried to do this using a system of equations but this becomes insoluble, so I wonder if I have misinterpreted the approach for how to obtain the coordinates of the polynomial p in base B'? This is how I have tried to solve this:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + B\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + C\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + D\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Hence they want the polynomial in base B'?